# Convert PHP script to ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net

Does anyone know how to write the following PHP in ASP.NET(VB.NET)?

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) : 
  $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item"; 
endforeach;
```

The data in $_GET['listItem'] looks like this:

item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3

Comment: Could you explain the intent, and maybe I can help more, as I know nothing about PHP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a little PHP but I'm assuming that $position is a zero-based index. If it's not, then you would swap the two lines of code that declare the position variable. Comments begin with the ' character.

```
'Request.Params accesses parameters from form posts, query string, etc.
Dim pairs = Request.Params("listItem").Split("&")

For i As Integer = 0 To pairs.Length - 1

  Dim token = pairs(i)
  Dim position = i.ToString()
  'string position = (i + 1).ToString();
  Dim id = Convert.ToInt32(token.Split("=")(1))
  Dim sql = "UPDATE table SET position = " + position + " WHERE [id] = " + id.ToString()
  'This line does the same thing, a bit more eloquently and efficiently
  'Dim sql = String.Format("UPDATE table SET position = {0} WHERE [id] = {1}", position, id.ToString())

Next
```

---

I did this in C# first because I did not notice that you said VB.net.  So here's the C# version.  Thought I might as well leave it in.
I made this a little wordy to demonstrate some of the nuances of C# and for clarity.

```
// Request.Params accesses parameters from form posts, query string, etc.
string[] pairs = Request.Params["listItem"].Split('&');
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++)
{
  string token = pairs[i];
  string position = i.ToString();
  // string position = (i + 1).ToString();
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(token.Split('=')[1]);
  string sql = "UPDATE table SET position = " + position + " WHERE [id] = " + id;
  // This line does the same thing, a bit more eloquently and efficiently
  //string sql = String.Format("UPDATE table SET position = {0} WHERE [id] = {1}", position, id.ToString());
}
```